# Code-First Migration not returning List for dropdownlist from Existing SQL table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Still studying the use of Code-First so please bear with me here.

I am trying to return a List into a Dropdownlist (the source of this data comes from an existing SQL table that contains products)

Here is the class I created (and migrated)

```
    public class Requirements
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Display(Name ="Requested By")]
       public string requestedBy { get; set; }

       public ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }

       [Display(Name ="Select Specification")]
        public byte ProductGroupId { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the existing table (This I imported using the EF import for Code First, it then created this class along with the DBcontext stuff - When I click on the db table and say Show Data, I can see the data, so it works)

```
    public ProductGroup()
   {

       public int id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [StringLength(255)]
       public string product_group { get; set; } 
   }
```

I created a viewmodel for the 2 classes to be combined:

```
  public class NewRequirementsVM
  {
    public IEnumerable<ProductGroup> ProductGroups { get; set; }
    public Requirements Requirements { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is the dropdownlist in my View:

```
   <div class="form-group w-75">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Requirements.ProductGroupId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Requirements.ProductGroupId, new SelectList(Model.ProductGroups, "Id", "product_group"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

And here is the code in the controller, suppose to get the List.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Specifications_ProductGroup = _context.ProductGroup.ToList();
        var viewModel = new NewRequirementsVM
        {
            ProductGroups = Specifications_ProductGroup
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I am trying to return the list of "product_group" names in the dropdown but all I get is "Select".

Where am I going wrong? Obviously this list is not pulling through, where is my mistake/s?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're populating the Requirements property of the ViewModel, for one thing.  Second, do you know for sure that your `Specifications_ProductGroup` variable has any contents?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that gets generated on your view for the dropdown?

Comment: @Ann L. The Specifications_ProductGroup variable doesn't get populated. When debugging through it, this var gets nothing.